# How to fix extra Excel documents after conversion from PDF?

Tags: excel, vba

The problem is that after converting from PDF to Excel, when browsing to save the output file it creates additional blank Excel file, no idea why. Maybe due to the For loop or due to the Saving and Closing code?

If I convert 2 PDFs it outputs 2 converted Excel files and 2 additional blank Excel documents.

Any help would be more than appreciated.

Below is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub PDF_To_Excel()
    Dim setting_sh As Worksheet
    Set setting_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setting")
    Dim pdf_path As String
    Dim excel_path As String

    pdf_path = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.PDF), *.PDF", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")

    excel_path = setting_sh.Range("E12").Value

    Dim objFile As File
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim fo As Folder
    Dim f As File
    Set objFile = fso.GetFile(pdf_path)
    sPath = Left(objFile.Path, Len(objFile.Path) - Len(objFile.Name))
    Set fo = fso.GetFolder(sPath)
    Dim wa As Object
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim wr As Object

    Set wa = CreateObject("word.application")
    'Dim wa As New Word.Application
    wa.Visible = False
    'Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim nwb As Workbook
    Dim nsh As Worksheet
    'Dim wr As Word.Range

    For Each f In fo.Files
        Set doc = wa.documents.Open(f.Path, False, Format:="PDF Files")
        Set wr = doc.Paragraphs(1).Range
        wr.WholeStory

        Set nwb = Workbooks.Add
        Set nsh = nwb.Sheets(1)

        wr.Copy
        nsh.Activate 'Pastespecial like this needs to use an active sheet (according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.pastespecial)
        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:=1, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False

        Dim oILS As Shape 
        Set oILS = nsh.Shapes(nsh.Shapes.Count)

        With oILS
            .PictureFormat.CropLeft = 5
            .PictureFormat.CropTop = 150
            .PictureFormat.CropRight = 320
            .PictureFormat.CropBottom = 250
        End With
        With oILS
            .LockAspectRatio = True
        '    .Height = 260
        '    .Width = 450
        End With
        nsh.Shapes(nsh.Shapes.Count).Top = Sheets(1).Rows(1).Top

        Dim IntialName As String
        Dim sFileSaveName As Variant
        'IntialName = "Name.xlsx"
        sFileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("Name.xlsx", "Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
        If sFileSaveName <> False Then
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sFileSaveName

            doc.Close True
            nwb.Close True
        End If

    Next

    wa.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times. Instead respond in comments to your original question, or edit your original question (and leave a comment) if you need to add information, or update it.

Comment: Okay, but nobody seemed to answer it properly.

Comment: Ehhm, really? You asked that other question just 5 hours ago. I guess not everyone is waiting here just to work for you. It can take some time (some days sometimes) until someone who is able to give an answer comes accross your question. So more patience please.